# Beamer changing part numbers to letter

Tags: beamer, numbering, parts

Hi I'd like to change Rome numbers of parts into letters, for instance:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usecolortheme{whale}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

\title{This is a title}
\author{Author}
\date{ }
\begin{document}
\part{Review of Previous Lecture}
\frame{\partpage}
\frame{...}

\part{Today's Lecture}
\frame{\partpage}
\frame{...}

\end{document}
```

And I want to have Part A instead of Part I, etc.

Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```latex
\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd*\insertromanpartnumber{\@Alph\c@part}
\makeatother
```

Maybe you can redefine the content of `\insertromanpartnumber`, beacuse the default part number in part page is `\insertromanpartnumber`.